# Second order integer cone and polar

Tags: convex-analysis

Consider the two sets $C_1$ and $C_2$  that are defined as follows:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
C_1=\{\,(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \Bbb{R}^3 \mid x_3\ge 0\,,\,x_3^2 \ge x_1^2+x_2^2\,\} &,\\
\\
C_2=\{\,y\in \Bbb{R}^3 \mid \forall x \in C_1 \,,\, y^t\cdot x \le 0\,\} &.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Suppose that 
$$
C_3 =\{\,y\in \Bbb{R}^3 \mid \forall x \in C_1\cap \Bbb{Z}^3 \,,\,y^t\cdot x \le 1 \, \} 
$$

*My question:* How to prove that $C_2=C_3$?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Should it read $\le 0$ in $C_3$ as well?

Comment: no. Its important that $\le 1$

Comment: I just realized that changing it to $\le 0$ does not change $C_3$. Indeed, for each $x \in C_1 \cap \mathbb Z^3$, you have $n \, x \in C_1 \cap \mathbb Z^3$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Hence, $y^\top x \le \frac1n$ which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: and how do u reach that C2=C3?

Comment: By showing that $C_2^\circ = C_3^\circ$. Since both $C_2$ and $C_3$ are closed, convex cones, this yields $C_2 = C_3$ by the bipolar theorem.

Comment: and how do u do that?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is "u"?

Comment: and how do i do that? -thanks

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary set $C \subset \mathbb R^3$, we define the polar cone via
$$C^\circ = \{y \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \forall x \in C : y^\top x \le 0\}.$$

Then, we have
$$C_2^\circ = C_1$$
from the bipolar theorem and, similarly,
$$C_3^\circ = \operatorname{clcone}( C_1 \cap \mathbb Z^3 ),$$
where $\operatorname{clcone}(B)$ is the closed, convex, conical hull, i.e., the smallest closed convex cone containing $B$.

Finally, one can check
$$C_1 = \operatorname{clcone}( C_1 \cap \mathbb Z^3 ).$$

Comment: yes - how will u do that?

Comment: Actually you didn't do the $99 %$ %  of problem.

Comment: @Ashkan: Actually, I did not intend to offer a full solution. My answer give some hints to attack the problem, only some (rather straightforward) calculations in between are missing. Somebody who want to understand the topic should fill the details him/herself.